# Continue uploading process in background IOS

Tags: ios, dropbox

I was wondering if it was possible to continue the uploading of a file in the background. for example when the user puts the iPad in sleep, the uploading continues...

I asked this question in the dropbox forums as well since I am uploading to dropbox using the core API. This was the answer:

"Using the core API, uploading is entirely in the control of your app.  You can request that the OS keep your app alive in the background, which it will allow for a maximum of 10 minutes before suspending your app.  You can see more information here: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html
If you use the new Sync API, this will all be done automatically by the API."

I am posting here because I didn't understand what they mean by 'request that the OS keep your app alive in the background'. Does this mean I have to request the ios wi a specific code, and it has nothing to do with dropbox, or it is a particular dropbox function?

Comment: Can you link to your question in dropbox forum?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to ask the OS to keep the app running, it has nothing to do with Dropbox... When you start uploading, do this:

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
}];
```

... and store the `bgTask` somewhere. Then when your upload completes or fails, do this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
```

That will tell the OS to keep your app running because there's a background task running...

Comment: It's important to mention that: "Each task you mark will have roughly 10 minutes (total) to complete its actions, plenty of time for most common uses. After the time completes, the application is suspended and treated like any other suspended application." (Quoted from this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/124159/Hour-21-Building-Background-Aware-Applications)

Comment: Thanks, very neat answer, but I have a doubt: how can I determine if the uploadis complete if I am not in the app itself? Wont other functions of my app be blocked? Can I insert the endBackgroundTask call in a normal void method?

Comment: Yes if you've called the first function while your app was in the foreground then when it enters the background it'll continue to run normally until you call the second function to let the system know that you're done...

Comment: And can you launch multiple background tasks at the same time? Imagine you want to upload five different files, if you create a new instance of the `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier` for each of them, will the other 4 continue when the 1st one calls `endBackgroundTask`?

Comment: @Jules Yep, just remember to call `endBackgroundTask` for each one

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

By requesting, it means that when your App Delegate method applicationDidEnterBackground gets called you have about 5 seconds to finish up.  As you are doing a long upload, you can request additional time via beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler

Answer (score 0):

New Dropbox SDK provides the functionality of background uploading/Downloading of files. Please try using new SDK. Have a happy coding.

Comment: Are you talking about the Dropbox iOS SDK? Because I can't find the support for uploading/downloading files in background in the latest version 1.3.5.

Comment: Then try by using beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler for uploading/downloading.. This might help you out.

Answer (score -3):

I guess this worked for me.

1. disabled autolock
2. disabled screentimeout
3. plugged in to power
4. Enable location services on iphone for dropbox and background running option
5. left the dropbox app open
6. more than 2000 photos & videos upload successfully